# Binary Image Corner Detection

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, image-processing, robotics

I have a matrix that represents a binary image (1 for each cell that represents "black" pixels and 0 for "white" ones). The black pixels represent the figures (shape and fill) of the image and the white ones the background. What I want to do is to detect the corners of the figures represented in the matrix.

2 examples:

---

[image]

---

Any idea or algorithm for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example image?

Comment: Sure, images like: [Squares](http://www.hjoseph.com/shared/squares.png) and [Caves](http://www.hjoseph.com/shared/cave.png)

Comment: And what exactly are the corners? The bounding box? Something else?

Comment: If I have a image with the size 20 x 20, I get a matrix of 20 X 20 cells... so, let's suppose that the image has a square of size 5 that begin in the cell (3,2)... this means that the cornes of that figure are (3,2), (7,2), (3,6) and (7,6). As you can see, you are just matching the corners of one figure represented in the image. So, I need to detect all corners represented in the matrix.

Comment: @Harph It's almost clear for the squares above. BUt it's not clear enough for the "caves" below. Could you markup the corners in the caves graphs?

Comment: @belisarius you're right, I was reading and caves example is not a posible input case... not round figures in the input image.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [opencv libraries](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), they have [python bindings](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html) and a lot of algorithms to do corner detection.

my2c

Comment: The python reference is here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html Here is a c++ example using opencv http://www.moosechips.com/2008/08/opencv-corner-detection-using-cvgoodfeaturestotrack/ and a short howto using harris detection http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/42254

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there is a template using C++ that allows you to scan each pixel, and you could do that and replace the black's with 1's and white with 0's.

I had to do a similar thing when I did webcam color detection with opencv. I can show you the part of the code im talking about if you like? Although I may be misunderstanding your question. However my code allows you to scan each pixel (or frame altho mine is taken from a web-cam you could do the same with an actual picture too)

Comment: I already have the matrix with the binary representation of the image. What I need is to know which of the cells are the corners of the figures represented in the image. I.E: If I have a image with the size 20 x 20, I get a matrix of 20 X 20 cells... so, let's suppose that the image has a square of size 5 that begin in the cell (3,2)... this means that the cornes of that figure are (3,2), (7,2), (3,6) and (7,6). As you can see, you are just matching the corners of one figure represented in the image. So, I need to detect all corners represented in the matrix.

Comment: Oh Ok i was a bit confused. Ya the corner detection listed by macarthy would prolly be your best bet.